# Gerenciamento de quantidade em estoque C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Não consigo encontrar uma solução para gerenciamento de estoque e vendas.

O cenário seria um estoque de Autopeças, onde eu cadastro a entrada de um produto no estoque com uma determinada quantidade.

> cod  -  nome - qtd - vlr
>
> 3239 - Bomba de água - 2 - R$300,00

e logo eu quero adicionar mais 3 quantidades do mesmo item totalizando **5** itens da Bomba de água, ou reduzindo as quantidades conforme forem efetuadas as vendas.

talvez algum IF, FOR, COLLECTION

```
Ex:
   If (cod == cod)  
     {  
       ++1 qtd  
     }
```

Eu tenho um banco de dados Access, estou acessando direto no banco sem ser DataSet:

Um exemplo de como estou gravando os dados hoje no db:

```
        OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbqtd;

        Con.Open();
        OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
        Cmm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO estoque (codproduto, nome, qtd, local, numero) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
        Cmm.Parameters.Clear();

        Cmm.Parameters.Add("@codproduto", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtCodProd.Text;
        Cmm.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtNome.Text;
        Cmm.Parameters.Add("@qtd", OleDbType.VarChar,50).Value = txtQtd.Text;
        Cmm.Parameters.Add("@local", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLocal.Text;
        Cmm.Parameters.Add("@numero", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtNumero.Text;
        
        Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmm.Connection = Con;

        Cmm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Inclusão efetuada com Sucesso !");
```

Comment: Use o operador [`+=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx), ex.: `qtd += 3`

Comment: @zekk Não consegui fazer funcionar, ou não entendi direito como faz.
poderia colocar uma explicação mais completa por favor  ?

Comment: Você quer incrementar antes ou depois de salvar no banco?

Comment: A situação aqui é a seguinte: 
Eu insiro um produto no meu estoque com a coluna QTD valendo **1** inicialmente. se posteriormente eu precisar inserir este mesmo item e ele ainda constar **1** em meu estoque, eu gostaria que ele não duplicasse e sim transformasse o valor em **2**.

Comment: Você pode consultar a quantidade de tal produto num `select ...`, por o número numa variável `x` e verificar se é igual a *1*, se for, você incrementa `x` assim: `x += 1`, e então você atualiza o campo `qtd` desse produto com a variável `x`.

Comment: @MaurícioSanches, como o zekk disse, você tem que verificar se contém o produto na tabela. Se o produto existir você atualiza a quantidade com o comando UPDATE, senão você insere esse produto na tabela com as quantidades que deseja utilizando o comando INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Galera,
Consegui resolver o problema de acordo com o que o Zekk e o Diego disseram.

(trabalhei a soma da quantidade em Textboxs ocultos, para não ter que somar em variáveis).

Segue:

```
  private void btnInclude_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbqtd;

        string qtdvar = "";

        Con.Open();

        OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
        Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT qtd FROM estoque WHERE codproduto = '" + codprod.Text + "' ";
        Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmm.Connection = Con;

        qtdvar = Convert.ToString(Cmm.ExecuteScalar());

        Con.Close();

        qtdestoque.Text = qtdvar;

        if (qtdvar == "")
        {
            // QTD TEM VALOR

            OleDbConnection Coninsert = new OleDbConnection();
            Coninsert.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbqtd;

            Coninsert.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmminsert = new OleDbCommand();
            cmminsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO estoque (codproduto, nome, qtd, location, numero) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
            cmminsert.Parameters.Clear();

            cmminsert.Parameters.Add("@codproduto", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = codprod.Text;
            cmminsert.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtNome.Text;
            cmminsert.Parameters.Add("@qtd", OleDbType.Integer, 18).Value = txtQtd.Text;
            cmminsert.Parameters.Add("@local", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLocal.Text;
            cmminsert.Parameters.Add("@numero", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtNumero.Text;

            cmminsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmminsert.Connection = Coninsert;

            cmminsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Inclusão efetuada com Sucesso !");

            //===== Recarregar DataGrid
            OleDbConnection Con1 = new OleDbConnection();
            Con1.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbqtd;

            Con1.Open();

            OleDbCommand Cmm1 = new OleDbCommand();
            Cmm1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM estoque";
            Cmm1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmm1.Connection = Con1;

            OleDbDataReader DR1;
            DR1 = Cmm1.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Load(DR1);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
            dataGridView2.Refresh();

            Con1.Close();

        }
        else
        {
         //========= QTD TEM VALOR


            qtdresult.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(qtd.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(qtdestoque.Text));


            OleDbConnection Conupdate = new OleDbConnection();
            Conupdate.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbqtd;


            Conupdate.Open();
            OleDbCommand Cmmupdate = new OleDbCommand();
            Cmmupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE estoque SET qtd = ? WHERE codproduto = ?    ";
            Cmmupdate.Parameters.Clear();

            Cmmupdate.Parameters.Add("@qtd", OleDbType.Integer, 18).Value = Convert.ToInt32(qtdresult.Text);
            Cmmupdate.Parameters.Add("@codprod", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = codprod.Text;



            Cmmupdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmmupdate.Connection = Conupdate;

            Cmmupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Alteração efetuada com Sucesso !");

            Conupdate.Close();


            //===== Recarregar DataGrid
            OleDbConnection Con1 = new OleDbConnection();
            Con1.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbqtd;

            Con1.Open();

            OleDbCommand Cmm1 = new OleDbCommand();
            Cmm1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM estoque";
            Cmm1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Cmm1.Connection = Con1;

            OleDbDataReader DR1;
            DR1 = Cmm1.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Load(DR1);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
            dataGridView2.Refresh();

            Con1.Close();

        }
      }
```